# How to write a query to determine if 'AB' and 'BA' are the same?

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I am a bit stuck here. I'm trying to assign a unique route ID of each route whether it's oneway or round trip.

For example I have two columns, origin and destination:

- DC to NYC -> routeA
- NYC to DC -> routeA
- NYC to Boston -> routeB
- Boston to Miami -> routeC
- Miami to NYC -> routeD
- Miami to Boston -> routeC

In other words, how can I write a query to flag DC to NYC and NYC to DC essentially the same route (routeA) as opposed to being a distinct route. In this case, I only care about the city pair, not the direction of travel.

PS: I'm using MySQL

Thanks!

Comment: You could concat and order the cities and then group by the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate the pairs by doing something like:

```
select least(origin, destination) as city1,
       greatest(origin, destination) as city2,
       (@route := @route + 1) as route_number
from t cross join
     (select @route := 0) params
group by least(origin, destination), greatest(origin, destination);
```

Or, an alternative would be to create a route name:

```
select t.*,
       concat_ws(':', least(origin, destination) as city1,
                 greatest(origin, destination) 
                ) as route_name
from t;
```

Comment: I like the 2nd one myself, but who names their tables "t"?

Comment: The alternate works exactly what I wanted it. Thank you so much! I never thought of least() and greatest() functions.